# What is the difference between build().perform() and perform()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Some articles suggest
that now `build()` is included in `perform()` itself, while others suggest
that `build().perform()` is used when multiple actions are to be chained
together.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`build()` is included in `perform()`, you can see it in the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.java)

```
public void perform() {
    build().perform();
}
```

The `perform()` inside the methods calls the `perform()` method in the inner class `BuiltAction`.

Calling `build().perform()` in your code is actually calling `build()` twice, `build().build().perform()`.

[build](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#build--)

> Generates a composite action containing all actions so far, ready to
>   be performed (and resets the internal builder state, so subsequent
>   calls to build() will contain fresh sequences).

[performe](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#perform--)

> A convenience method for performing the actions without calling
>   build() first.

This is little misleading (IMO), because `build()` is being called, even if implicitly.

Comment: I checked the source code and found that indeed, build() is implicitly called inside perform()

Answer (score 4):

`build()` method in Actions class is use to **create chain** of action or operation you want to perform.

`perform()` this method in Actions Class is use to **execute** chain of action which are build using Action build method.

`build().perform()` = create chain of actions + execute

Answer (score 0):

1. build() -
   Generates a composite action containing all actions so far, ready to be performed (and resets the internal builder state, so subsequent calls to build() will contain fresh sequences).
2. perform()
   A convenience method for performing the actions without calling build() first.

So, whenever going for composite actions (multiple actions) use build().perform(), else perform().